# android studio get string value from another method

Tags: android

I have a method getLastLocation() that containg two strings city and country, the problem is when
I try to set the string to textview outside of the method I get empty value, it only works when I set the string to textview inside the method,

any help will be appreciated.

here is my code:

getLastLocation();

```
String city;
String country;

Textview cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
Textview countryText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_country);

    cityText .setText(country);
    countryText .setText(city);


        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getLastLocation(){
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                                Location location = task.getResult();
                                if (location == null) {
                                    requestNewLocationData();
                                } else {

                                    MyLat = location.getLatitude();
                                    MyLong = location.getLongitude();


                                    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                                    for(String provider: lm.getAllProviders()) {
                                        @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") Location location1 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                                        if(location!=null) {
                                            try {
                                                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location1.getLatitude(), location1.getLongitude(), 1);
                                                if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {


         city = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();  ///////string I want to get <<<---------
         country =  addresses.get(0).getLocality(); ///////string I want to get <<<---------

                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {}
```

You have a listener in your code. Even if you put getLastLocation() first, there is no guarantee that city, country strings will have value assigned.

```
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task)
```

Above method will only be executed when the corresponding task is completed.

Whatever code you've written below getLastLocation() will be executed without the onCompleted() necessarily triggered.

So you get null instead of actual value in the textViews.

To avoid this you have to update textviews inside the OnComplete() method.

If you still want to update textviews outide of getLastLocation(), add delay to set textView's value

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cityText .setText(country);
            countryText .setText(city);
        }
    },5000); //textviews will be set value after 5 seconds, assuming that OnComplete() inside getLastLocation() will be triggered within 5 seconds.
```

Comment: But this is not preferable. Sometimes it could take more than 5 seconds. It is best to update inside oncomplete()

Answer (score 0):

According to what i got from your Question,
You are setting string value to textview before you call the getLastLocation() function and that time your string(city and country) is empty or null;

first you will have to call the method and then set it to texview, that will work fine.

```
getLastLocation() ;

cityText .setText(country);
countryText .setText(city);
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, I tried your code but it also show null value.

Comment: Then, I think here the variables are not getting values.
`city = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
country =  addresses.get(0).getLocality();`

check it once, maybe functions running asynchronously so that while function is running, values are also setting to textview at same time

Comment: function must complete its execution before setting to textview